# Spurious failures on discovery client connecting to discovery server

Tags: spring-cloud

We are noticing a number of random failures on the spring cloud services that we created trying to connect to the discovery server.  They seem to happen every now and then and so far have not caused discovery to fail.

However, out operations group is reporting this to us a possible issue and we are trying to investigate.  Is there any condition that we should be concerned about.

The example that I am showing below is that i replicated the same issue running on my laptop with the service and discovery server (eureka) on the same machine, so networking as a cause seems to be not the issue.

015-08-10 10:41:51.592  INFO 9897 --- [pool-8-thread-1] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8761: The target server failed to respond
2015-08-10 10:41:51.593  INFO 9897 --- [pool-8-thread-1] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8761

Comment: will you file an issue?

Comment: sure, created here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/483